# Reshape/convert study-level meta-analysis to individual patients data meta-analysis

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have study-level meta-analysis data that I want to reshape/convert it to patients level data

Here is a sample of my data

```r
data2<-read.table(text="STUDY   TOTAL   POAF    Age_POAF
CRESWELL, 1993  3983    1378    99
ARANKI, 1996    570 189 77
KOLVEKAR, 1997  50  25  NA
ALMASSI, 1997   3855    1143    66.8
TAMIS, 2000 216 55  NA
STAMOU, 2000    969 206 69
HAKALA, 2002    3676    1141    63.9
HRAVNAK, 2002   814 260 69.6
SILVA, 2004 158 45  NA
VILLAREAL, 2004 6475    994 66
",header=T, sep="\t")
```

I want it to create 3983 rows (number of TOTAL cases) all of them labeled as 'CRESWELL, 1993' in the study column and in the POAF first 1378 (number of cases with POAF) should be labeled as `Yes` or `1` while the remaining as `No` or `0`, and all of them has `Age_POAF` column as 99, then we move to the second line of the original data and create 570 rows

For example be as follows

```
STUDY           TOTAL   POAF   Age_POAF
CRESWELL, 1993  3983    Yes    99
CRESWELL, 1993  3983    Yes    99
CRESWELL, 1993  3983    Yes    99
CRESWELL, 1993  3983    Yes    99
...      ...    ....   ...   ....
ARANKI, 1996    570     Yes   77
ARANKI, 1996    570     Yes   77
ARANKI, 1996    570     Yes   77
...      ...    ....   ...   ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `uncount()` the `TOTAL` column to expand your dataset, then a simple `ifelse` to assign correct `POAF` values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

uncount(data2, TOTAL, .remove = F) |> 
  mutate(POAF = ifelse(row_number() <= POAF, "Yes", "No"), .by = STUDY)
```

Some sample rows:

```r
             STUDY TOTAL POAF Age_POAF
1376 CRESWELL,1993  3983  Yes       99
1377 CRESWELL,1993  3983  Yes       99
1378 CRESWELL,1993  3983  Yes       99
1379 CRESWELL,1993  3983   No       99
1380 CRESWELL,1993  3983   No       99
1381 CRESWELL,1993  3983   No       99
...
3982 CRESWELL,1993  3983   No       99
3983 CRESWELL,1993  3983   No       99
3984   ARANKI,1996   570  Yes       77
3985   ARANKI,1996   570  Yes       77
3986   ARANKI,1996   570  Yes       77
```